# Custom UIView with UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I have a `UIView` with two UILabel that I want to reuse in more than one `UIViewController`. I use storyboard and I assign a custom class `alertView:UIView` that I declared.
file AlertRemote.h

```
@interface AlertRemote: UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
-(void) setTextLabel;
```

file AlertRemote.m

```
-(void) setTextLabel{
    [ _label1 setText:@"attention..."];
    [_label2 setText:@"the program..."];
}
```

file Controllo.m

```
//the view present in the storyboard alertView linked to the uiview
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet AlertRemote *alertView; 
@property AlertRemote *alRemView;
[super viewDidLoad];
_alertView=_alRemView; [_alertView setTextLabel];
[_alertView setTextLabel];
```

if I put some breakpoints inside setTextLabel the code don't works
thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you use directly the `AlertRemote` IBOutlet to set text ? 

`alRemView` is needed ? what do you do with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the custom alert to work, you need to initialise it.

```
AlertRemote *alRemView;

alRemView = [[AlertRemote alloc]init];
[alRemView setTextLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not initializing the property alertview. If you are initializing the property alertview then try to set directly with out using alremView.